# Declaring Handler error

Tags: java, android, handler

I got a code snippet for the Handler in android Java and it tells me to delete the parentheses around the postDelayed parameters.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed (runable, minute);
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        biomass = biomass +1;
    }
};
```

I want the program to increment biomass by 1 after a minute.
minute has been declared above as int minute = 60000;

The code snippet I used is here: www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Comment: this does not compile. i suggest you post your actual code. the declaration of the runnable and the call to postDelayed cannot be in the same scope the way you write them (java 101)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by scope; I understand it to mean the access rights (private, package, public).

Comment: scope means the declaration of your runnable appears to be outside a method, as the runnable is a member (indicated by the presence of the access modifier), while the call to postDelayed is necessarly in a method or in a static block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause your Thread/Runnable with Thread.sleep(6000) where 6000 is number of milliseconds

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        biomass = biomass +1;
    }
};
```

new Thread(runnable).start();

Comment: That seems to pause the whole app and wait a minute before anything else is done

Comment: aouch. worst solution of the day.

Comment: I was asking on behalf of my sister and she tried it and it worked. Although I do find the other answers more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              biomass = biomass +1;
                          }
                        }, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing runnable before defining it.private cant be define there

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed (runnable,c);
```